# Java logs analyses

Tags: java, logging

I have a Java solution and customer requirements include that we should provide logs in any format and provide a tool to read these logs with easy settings to analyse those data.

My question here is which is better? to create logs with custom format or there is general standards to follow on writing the logs (for example, Apache server logs style).

If there is standards that I should follow, is there tools to read and analyse without extra coding efforts?

Comment: What you are looking for is log4j https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: And the tool for analyzing the files is chainsaw https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/

Comment: Yes, I want  to use log4j, the tool is ok, but how to set a standard format ? how to set the columns like error, message, .... and the tool understand it